# How do I push helm charts to Amazon ECR

Tags: kubernetes-helm, amazon-ecr

I have a helm chart that I want to push to ECR but I keep hitting 401 Unauthorized.

```
$ helm chart list
REF                                         NAME                    VERSION     DIGEST  SIZE        CREATED 
myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world   hello-world             1.0.0+1     6c7c951 135.3 KiB   23 hours

$ helm chart push myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world:1.0.0
The push refers to repository [1myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/helloworld]
ref:     myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world:1.0.0
digest:  6c7c9512d309b04816afd17dcdaaa64d0492550d8e290155973ddab125815da7
size:    135.3 KiB
name:    hello-world
version: 1.0.0+1
Error: unexpected response: 401 Unauthorized
```

I also tried authenticating the ECR with helm with `helm registry login myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com` but the credentials that I got from `aws sts get-caller-identity` does not work.

```
$ aws sts get-caller-identity
{
    "UserId": "<USERID>",
    "Account": "<Account>",
    "Arn": "arn:aws:iam::<Account>:user/foo"
}

$ helm registry login myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Username: <USERID>
Password: 
Error: login attempt to https://myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/v2/ failed with status: 401 Unauthorized
```

My helm version is v3.0.2.
Does helm not support ECR as a registry for charts?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I found the answer so I'm answering my own question.

To authenticate helm with ECR, run:

```
TOKEN=`aws ecr get-login --region ${REGION} --registry-ids ${ACCOUNT} | cut -d' ' -f6`

helm registry login myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com
Username: AWS
Password: $TOKEN
```

The above will authenticate helm with ECR, however, looks like ECR doesn't support ORAS (OCI Registry As Storage). In other words, you cannot push helm charts to it just yet.

```
$ helm chart push myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world:1.0.0
The push refers to repository [myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world]
ref:     myecr.us-east-2.amazonaws.com/hello-world:2.0.0
digest:  6c7c9512d309b04816afd17dcdaaa64d0492550d8e290155973ddab125815da7
size:    135.3 KiB
name:    hello-world
version: 1.0.0+1
Error: failed commit on ref "manifest-sha256:262e1e34f4762606ec011c776944636c003969a2cfb289776fa0f7c26883f7ad": unexpected status: 405 Method Not Allowed
```

The issue is tracked here: https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/308

Update: ECR support for helm chart is live https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/userguide/push-oci-artifact.html

Comment: I couldn't use the command you supplied and needed to use `aws ecr get-login-password --region us-east-2`. But your answer worked otherwise.

Answer (score 4):

The safest and most secure with AWS CLI 2 is to pipe the token returned by aws get-login-password to helm registry login, this way the token is not stored anywhere ever. You may also need to set `HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1` in your environment to use this feature:

```
$ aws --version
aws-cli/2.0.41 Python/3.7.3 ...
$ ECR_HOST="<ACCOUNT>.dkr.ecr.<REGION>.amazonaws.com"
$ export HELM_EXPERIMENTAL_OCI=1
$ aws ecr get-login-password | helm registry login --username AWS --password-stdin $ECR_HOST
Login succeeded
```

Now you can push a chart from local registry. First save it to local:

```
$ helm chart save path/to/your-chart $ECR_HOST/your-chart:VERSION
ref:     <ECR_HOST>/your-chart:1.0
digest:  466005961...
size:    2.1 KiB
name:    your-chart
version: <Chart.yml "version">
1.0: saved

$ helm chart list
REF                     NAME        VERSION             DIGEST  SIZE    CREATED   
<ECR_HOST>/your-cha...  your-chart  2020.1.1-abc1234    4660059 2.1 KiB 40 seconds
```

Then push it to ECR:

```
$ helm chart push $ECR_HOST/your-chart:VERSION
The push refers to repository [<ECR_HOST>/your-chart]
ref:     <ECR_HOST>/your-chart:VERSION
digest:  46600596...
size:    2.1 KiB
name:    your-chart
version: 2020.1.1-abc1234
1.0: pushed to remote (1 layer, 2.1 KiB total)
```

Proof that it is there:

```
$ helm chart list
REF                     NAME        VERSION             DIGEST  SIZE    CREATED   
<ECR_HOST>/your-char... your-chart  2020.1.1-abc1234    4660059 2.1 KiB 11 minutes
$ helm chart remove <ECR_HOST>/your-chart:1.0
1.0: removed

$ helm chart list
REF NAME    VERSION DIGEST  SIZE    CREATED

$ helm chart pull $ECR_HOST/your-chart:1.0
1.0: Pulling from <ECR_HOST>/your-chart
ref:     <ECR_HOST>/your-chart:1.0
digest:  4660059618c...
size:    2.1 KiB
name:    your-chart
version: 2020.1.1-abc1234
Status: Downloaded newer chart for <ECR_HOST>/your-chart:1.0

$ helm chart list
REF                     NAME        VERSION             DIGEST  SIZE    CREATED   
<ECR_HOST>/your-char... your-chart  2020.1.1-abc1234    4660059 2.1 KiB 13 minutes
```

However there are several things that will delay us adopting the ECR as a helm charts repo:

- `helm chart list` clips chart ref with ellipses when past a certain length and there doesn't seem to be a way to change this (helm 3.2.1), *very* annoying because it clips the VERSION portion which you need for other operations
- if you look in the ECR repo for your-chart, you will see an image with tag VERSION and there is no indication whatever that it is not a docker image but a chart; it looks like TAG is arbitrary so you could have TAG be "chart-VERSION" but this feels like a hack
- the correspondence between the chart version (from the Chart.yml) and the VERSION when you save the chart is unclear; in fact when you look in the ECR repo for your-chart, you do not see the `version` string that is inside the Chart.yml, you just see the tag you used when you saved the chart

All these make ECR-repo-as-helm-chart-repo feel unintuitive and early stage and not in fact ready for mainstream use in a team.

Comment: You can authenticate to an ECR but you still cannot push help charts or other non-image artifacts. Though https://github.com/aws/containers-roadmap/issues/308 is picking up some momentum and we may soon be able to start using ECR as ORAS.

Comment: @mandopaloooza I updated the answer to show how to push and pull from ECR repo after login

Comment: @Oliver you can differentiate between a helm chart and an image by looking at the `artifactMediaType` field of the DescribeImages response https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECR/latest/APIReference/API_DescribeImages.html

Comment: @richard thanks good to know, it's beyond me though why that info is not shown in console. And  still unclear why artifact can have a different version than the chart.

Answer (score 1):

In my case I was facing the below issue, it has nothing to do with helm registry login, nor helm-chart itself

```
Error: failed to do request: Post "https://3594XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/my-project/my-team/helm-charts/blobs/uploads/": EOF
```

The problem is with the repository name, I think AWS ECR expects helm-charts repository to be at the root level, so when I changed by repo
from

```
3594XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/v2/my-project/my-team/helm-charts
```

to

```
3594XXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/helm-charts
```

The push worked fine for me

```
ubuntu@c2d4a3dd14fd:~/my-bundle/helm-charts/mychart$ helm chart push 359XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/helm-charts:mychart_0.0.0_test
The push refers to repository [359XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/helm-charts]
ref:     359XXXXXXXX.dkr.ecr.us-west-2.amazonaws.com/helm-charts:mychart_0.0.0_test
digest:  273040563a534eba7XXXXafb315ed7df70ce384514cd250b5f725ecd5e3
size:    41.3 KiB
name:    mychart
version: 2.0.0
mychart_0.0.0_test: pushed to remote (1 layer, 41.3 KiB total)
```

Answer (score 1):

If you're getting the following error:

`Error: failed to do request: Post "https://account-id.dkr.ecr.us-east-1.amazonaws.com/v2/foo/bar/abc/abc/blobs/uploads/": EOF`

See this:

> I was having the same problem and figured it out.
>
> The chart's name declared in Chart.yaml file must be the same as the
> name of the ECR repository. Only then one can execute
>
> helm push foobar-X.Y.Z.tgz
> oci://.dkr.ecr..amazonaws.com/ and
> delegate ECR to know in which repository to store the chart.

https://github.com/helm/helm/issues/11017#issuecomment-1244059106

Thank you to `manuelnucci`

Answer (score 0):

Check if you are logged in with helm

Use `helm registry login` command to login to registry by passing registry address with port(if port is not default)

Login to registry using helm command

```
$ helm registry login -u myuser registrydomain:5000
Password:
Login succeeded
```

Logout

```
$ helm registry logout registrydomain:5000
Logout succeeded
```

> Official Documentation:
>   https://helm.sh/docs/topics/registries/#the-registry-subcommand

Comment: TIL that I found enter `AWS` for username and the output of `aws ecr get-login --region ${REGION} --registry-ids ${ACCOUNT} | cut -d' ' -f6` as the password for `helm registry login` when using ECR

Comment: Have you loggedin using 'helm registry login' before you push ?